# JSX rendered by nuxt dev server works, while the prod version doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, npm, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, jsx

I have a nuxt app with a component that uses JSX.  It works locally using `npm run dev`, but the dist build I get after running `npm run build` fails to properly render.

Here' the component's code:

```
<script>
import draggable from 'vuedraggable'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      columns: [
        { width: 2 },
        { width: 3 },
        { width: 4 }
      ]
    }
  },
  components: {
    draggable
  },
  render (h) {
    const buildColumn = (column, index) => {
      const result = (
        <v-col md={ column.width } cols="auto">
          <v-card>
            <v-row>
              <v-col>
                <v-icon class="handle">mdi-drag</v-icon>
              </v-col>
              <v-col>
                { index }
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      )
      return result
    }
    return (
      <v-container>
        <draggable handle=".handle" onEnd={ () => this.$emit('update-order', this.columns) } list={this.columns} tag="v-row" options={{ animation: 500 }}>
          { this.columns.map((column, index) => buildColumn(column, index)) }
        </draggable>
      </v-container>
    )
  }
}
</script>
```

When running npm run dev, it renders the following:

[image]

After building:

[image]

Can anyone help me figure out what could be causing this?  I'm including a base repo that demonstrates the problem

https://gitlab.com/qualisign/test_jsx

One more possible clue:

the first image is the non-working html one sees on the production server when inspecting the icons that fail to load:

[image]

this second image is how the working html looks when one inspects the same elements on the dev server:

[image]

I don't know if this helps, but I thought it might be relevant.

Comment: you are use v-bootstrap for this cards?

Comment: @SaZa  no, vuetify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** after looking the code shared by OP, this seems to be a [BUG #382](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module/issues/382) and is mentioned on the project repository as well.

There seems to be an issue with `vuetify-loaded` and to get around this issue, disabling `treeShake` option in the configuration like:

**nuxt.config.js**

```
{
...
    vuetify: {
        ...,
        treeShake: false
    }    
...
}
```

**Original answer:**

Looks like material icon library is not configured property due to which icons are not rendered. Check if following are configured properly as mentioned in the [guide](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/icons/#install-material-icons):

1. Check if `material-design-icons-iconfont` is installed

> npm install material-design-icons-iconfont -D

2. Check if css file is imported are on entry point of your app (index.js/app.js)

```js
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css' // Ensure you are using css-loader
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'md',
  },
})
```

If you are using CDN link for the library check if it is correct.
`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">`.

If this still doesn't work, check for all console and network errors, it's possible you have misconfigured style/font url somewhere in your app.

Comment: I tried your suggestions but couldn't get it to work.  In my repo (which I created using npx create-nuxt-app), Vuetify is instantiated in `.nuxt/vuetify/plugins.js`, so this is where I added the material import.  Also, I added a git repo of my app in my question if you want to see for yoruself.

Comment: @DavidJ. there seems to be an issue with vuetifyloader when tree shaking is enabled, which is enabled by default only for production mode. If you force tree shaking all the time same issue can be seen in dev version as well.